# Pixel Formats: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA vs AVVideoCodecJPEG

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, cmsamplebuffer

I am trying to figure out which performs better capturing JPEG with

**AVFoundatation** -> **PhotoCaptureDelegate**

I can use:

```
photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) ])
```

or

```
photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : [AVVideoQualityKey : 1.0]] as [String : Any])
```

I noticed that with **AVVideoCodecJPEG**, I can use compression quality; However, I can't use if I was doing any TIFF conversions or other tasks from **CMSampleBuffer** in **PhotoCaptureDelegate**.

YET, if I want to just save to JPEG in new way (guessing the most efficient way, I have to use **AVVideoCodecJPEG** to do:

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

    self.jpegPhotoData = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: photoSampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer)

    }
```

Which is better to use?

Comment: The api is deprecated. try `photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)`.    https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate